# Copy production Azure website to staging?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to copy (not swap) my production version of my azure website to a staging website I create? I would like to have an exact copy of my production website code in staging without replacing it which seems like what always happens with the swap option.

Comment: have you tried the backup feature? you can backup your site to blob storage and create a new one from it

Answer (score 0):

I found a current workaround for this as a solution. This does not seem to be in Azure as built in functionality (yet) see [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/6830040-add-button-to-copy-prod-to-staging-slot-instead-of):

1) FTP all production website data (wwwroot folder) down to local machine from production site

2) Create staging website in azure

3) FTP all production website data (wwwroot folder) now on local machine to staging website (wwwroot folder)

4) Launch staging website (it will now match production)